# How do I get rid of the BLACK background in a 101 frame animated gif with Photoshop?

Tags: animation, photoshop, gimp

I have this animated GIF that has a BLACK background.

It's 101 frames. I've opened in GIMP, PS, Paint.net, Paintshop Pro and to no avail, I do not know where to go or how to dump the black background.  It's a custom spinner and was made with another animation software from a VFX friend of mine. He exported to a GIF from his program, which was transparent, but when I got it, it's BLACK.

Here's the link. Please download and let me know the process:

http://tinyurl.com/opa3rd4

Appreciate anyone's graphic arts help.

Comment: For questions like this, considere posting on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com  (not sure if this could be migrated there with the included answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open your .gif in Photoshop and then in File > Save For Web, chose GIF and there's a button that sets color to transparent. Chose the colors you need to make transparent and press it
[image]

Comment: One quickie... do I need to do this for "each" layer by clicking the "eye" or do I need "all" layers visible first?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sergey, read my above comments and see what you think.  What I'm getting now is this:  http://webparity.net/images/logo-rotate-clockwise-amber-red.gif  and the original: http://webparity.net/images/logo-rotate-clockwise-amber-red-orig.gif  Thank you Sergey...

Comment: Nope, you don't need to touch layers, load gif in Photoshop and go to Save for Web, set transparent color and save: Photoshop will do the rest